# Understanding Inequalities from a Paper by L. Caffarelli, R. Kohn, and L. Nirenberg.

Tags: regularity-theory-of-pdes

I am a Computer Science student. For the fun I would like to have a better understanding about Navier-Stokes Existence and Smoothness problem. I am reading a paper from L. Caffarelli, R. Kohn and L. Nirenberg. The paper is titled: *Partial Regularity of Suitable Weak Solutions of the Navier-Stokes Equations*. Their are some inequalities which I do not understand. I would like to understand them so therefore I will describe them here.

Proposition 1. There are absolute constants $\epsilon_{1}$ and $C_{1} > 0$, and a constant $\epsilon_{2}(q)$ depending only on $q$, with the following property. Suppose $(u, p)$ is a suitable weak solution of the Navier-Stokes system on $Q_{1}$ with force $f \in L^{q}$, for some $q > \frac{5}{2}$, suppose further that
\begin{align}
\iint_{Q_{1}} \left(|u|^{3} + |u||p|\right) + \int^{0}_{-1} \left( \int_{|x| < 1} |p| dx \right)^{5/4} dt \leq \epsilon_{1}
\end{align}

and
\begin{align}
\iint_{Q_{1}} |f|^{q} \leq \epsilon_{2}
\end{align}

Then
\begin{align}
|u(x, t)| \leq C_{1}
\end{align}

The proposition is later used in the paper as a hypothesis. My primary question is:

What does the following inequality means:
\begin{align}
\iint_{Q_{1}} \left(|u|^{3} + |u||p|\right) + \int^{0}_{-1} \left( \int_{|x| < 1} |p| dx \right)^{5/4} dt \leq \epsilon_{1}
\end{align}

The primary question leads to two secondary questions:
 - How are such hypothesis established? 
 - Is there literature available about proving dedicated about this field of Mathematics?

Could someone provide some help? Thank you very much.

Comment: What is $Q_1$??

Comment: $Q_{1}$ is a parabolic cylinder of unit length.